# Access Kubernetes ingress remotely

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ip, kubernetes-ingress

I've set up a Kubernetes ingress with minikube, on a virtual machine of CentOS 7.6.
It finally works well in that machine, described as below:

```
Name:             my-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          172.17.0.2
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  localhost
              /route1/?(.*)   service1 (172.18.0.4:80)
              /route2/?(.*)   service2 (172.18.0.4:80)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
```

And I made my `/etc/hosts` as follow

```
172.17.0.2      localhost
172.17.0.2      0.0.0.0
```

Which works fine on the virtual machine, that I can successfully access my API through `curl localhost/route1/api/values`.

But here I would like to access this on other machine for developing.  My thought was to see the same successful result through `curl 192.168.2.21/route1/api/values` on other machine, with `192.168.2.21` the IP address of the virtual machine with Kubernetes.  But it failed with message "empty reply from server".

Is there other method that I can make this happen, accessing the result of ingress on other machine?

What I tried was to install [local-dev-with-docker-for-mac-kubernetes](https://github.com/jnewland/local-dev-with-docker-for-mac-kubernetes), but didn't help.
And also saw some other suggestions to work around services, but for I would have to work with a lot of services, afraid that may be hard to manage if I have to avoid any port duplicated.  So am looking for result workaround Ingress mainly.

Answer (score 2):

Your config specifying host as localhost, so only incoming traffic with localhost got handled. You can verify this with `curl 172.17.0.2/route1/api/values` from the same machine. Should get the same empty reply message.

To fix this, you can omit the host setting so ingress controller will handle all incoming HTTP traffics. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-rules

**UPDATE**

minimal ingress example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: testsvc
    servicePort: 80
```

Comment: That's right.  That IP doesn't work either even on that device.  It seems that the ingress only works with the host name given.  I'm checking out the link you gave and keep seeking a resolution to my needing scenario.  Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: host is optional, you can edit your ingress.yaml to remove it. Checkout this minimal ingress example: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource